# Database not published with vb

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access

I put database in bin->debug and i also call from that folder using DataDirectory Business_Card_Database.accdb when i publish the project database not found error is occur I cannot find solution plz help me

note I also tried
1. System.IO.Path.GetFullPath
2. Application.StartupPath
3. System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories
Above all are not working to find database after published

I'm  using
1. vb.net 2010 express edition
2. Access database 2010

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Did you just drop the file into the debug directory or did you include it as a resource? Any file you want to include with your project when it's published or deployed needs to be added as a resource. Right-click your project and choose "Properties." Find the "Resources" tab and click it. Make sure you're on the "Files" section (select that from the top row inside that tab page). Drag your database file into that window and it'll be included as a resource. You can reference it as `My.Resources.Business_Card_Database` when you need it in your code.